# gVim 8.2 bugeado tras instalación de plugins

Tags: python, windows, ide, vim

Tengo un ordenador con WIndows 10 y estoy intentando configurar un IDE con Vim para desarrollo en Python. He seguido las instrucciones de este blog:

https://juanjoalvarez.net/en/detail/2009/aug/4/vim-ide/

Pero, después de completar todos los pasos, gVim no se ejecuta al tratar de abrirlo con doble clik (haciendo esto no ocurre nada), ni tampoco usando el comando `vim` en el powershell. Esto es lo que aparece al intentarlo:

```
                               |
~                              |ion. Todos los derechos reservados.
~                              |
~                              |Shell multiplataforma https://aka.ms/pscore6
~                              |
~                              |vvim
~                              |econoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable.
~                              |nte el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e
~                              |vim
~                              |
~                              |
~                              |
~                              |
~                              |
~                              |
~                              |
~                              |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
```

Es como una especie de bug en el que el programa no se ejecuta correctamente. Supongo que he debido liarla con algún archivo de configuración o con los directorios, pero he seguido las instrucciones al pie de la letra.
Este es el contenido de mi archivo _vimrsc:

```
" Vim with all enhancements
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim

" Use the internal diff if available.
" Otherwise use the special 'diffexpr' for Windows.
if &diffopt !~# 'internal'
  set diffexpr=MyDiff()
endif
function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg1 = substitute(arg1, '!', '\!', 'g')
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = substitute(arg2, '!', '\!', 'g')
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = substitute(arg3, '!', '\!', 'g')
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      if empty(&shellxquote)
        let l:shxq_sav = ''
        set shellxquote&
      endif
      let cmd = '"' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  let cmd = substitute(cmd, '!', '\!', 'g')
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3
  if exists('l:shxq_sav')
    let &shellxquote=l:shxq_sav
  endif
endfunction

filetype plugin on

" F2 = OmniComplete
imap <f2> <c-x><c-o>

" Configuración del autocompletado inteligente (el de Python necesita un Vim
" compilado contra las librerías de Python para funcionar)
autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType html set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType css set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS

" Atajos para pestañas como los de Firefox/Chrome/Opera/etc
" Control T nueva pestaña (la cerramos con :q)
map <c-t> <esc>:tabnew<cr>
" Control PageUp/PageDown cambiar de pestaña
map <c-pageup> :tabp<cr>
map <c-pagedown> :tabn<cr>

" F10 activa modo pegar (no autoindenta, no descoloca lo que pegamos), F11
" lo desactiva
map <f10> :set paste<cr>
map <f11> :set nopaste<cr>

" Nuestros valores por defecto para el plugin Project
:let g:proj_flags="imstvcg"

" Colores que no te dejan ciego (al gusto del consumidor, se puede escribir
" :color e ir dando a tab para ver las combinaciones existentes, hay más en
" vim.org)
colors torte

" Que no haga la ventana de gvim demasiado pequeña
au GUIEnter * set lines=80 columns=160

" Plugin taglist

" F5 muestra el frame de tags
map <f5> :TlistToggle<cr>

" Poner el frame en la derecha que el Project ya lo pone a la izquierda
let Tlist_Use_Right_Window = 1

" Tamaño mínimo de frame de tags
let Tlist_WinWidth = 40

" Buffer explorer con F4
map <f4> \be
```

Y este es la estructura de directorios que ha quedado tras la configuración en el directorio $HOME/vimfiles:

```
PS $HOME\vimfiles> TREE /F
Listado de rutas de carpetas
El número de serie del volumen es ****-****
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   CHANGELOG
│   LICENCE
│   NERD_tree.zip
│   README.markdown
│
├───autoload
│   │   nerdtree.vim
│   │   pythoncomplete.vim
│   │
│   └───nerdtree
│           ui_glue.vim
│
├───colors
├───compiler
├───doc
│       bufexplorer.txt
│       NERD_commenter.txt
│       NERD_tree.txt
│       taglist.txt
│       tags
│
├───ftdetect
├───ftplugin
├───indent
├───keymap
├───lib
│   └───nerdtree
│           bookmark.vim
│           creator.vim
│           event.vim
│           flag_set.vim
│           key_map.vim
│           menu_controller.vim
│           menu_item.vim
│           nerdtree.vim
│           notifier.vim
│           opener.vim
│           path.vim
│           tree_dir_node.vim
│           tree_file_node.vim
│           ui.vim
│
├───nerdtree_plugin
│       exec_menuitem.vim
│       fs_menu.vim
│
├───plugin
│       bufexplorer.vim
│       mru.vim
│       NERD_commenter.vim
│       NERD_tree.vim
│       project.vim
│       pythonhelper.vim
│       taglist.vim
│       xml.vim
│
└───syntax
        nerdtree.vim
```

Aparte de no funcionar, parece que la consola en general se ha quedado bugeada; va muy lenta y a veces termina por bloquearse, como si la ejecución de Vim siguiese produciéndose en segundo plano.

Alguna idea? La verdad es que lo he intentado un par de veces con el mismo resultado, y no logro encontrar qué se me escapa

Comment: Bienvenido Tomasgon97 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Primero que nada: `vim -u NONE` para arrancar un editor sin levantar el `.vimrc`. Por otro lado, mi sugerencia, ve probando de a un pluggin por vez, alguno sin duda esta fallando. Por otro lado no uses el mecanismo de carga de pluggins tradicional, que te sugiere ese articulo, te recomiendo un plugin manager tipo https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim es mucho más cómodo, por que defines que plugins cargar desde el `.vimrc` y además puedes actualizarlos con un simple comando